# BeautifulSoup Python парсинг, упаковать в словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

На страничке в каждой строке пары данных, хочу упаковать в словарь "ключ, значение", написал вот такой 3-х проходный парсинг. может быть возможно сделать быстрее, за один проход?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(request(url), 'html.parser')
keys, vols = [], []
block = soup.find('table', class_='snapshot-table2')
for key  in block.find_all('td', class_='snapshot-td2-cp'): keys.append(key.text)
for valu in block.find_all('td', class_='snapshot-td2'): vols.append(valu.text)
base = dict(zip(keys, vols))
```

```
<table class="snapshot-table2">
<tbody><tr class="table-dark-row">
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key1</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value1</td>
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key2</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value2</td>
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key3</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-dark-row">
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key4</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value4</td>
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key5</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value5</td>
<td class="snapshot-td2-cp">Key6</td><td class="snapshot-td2">Value6</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```